# Compare two xml variables in sql query and get the difference?

Tags: sql-server

```
@oldXML = <root><row USER_KEY="1" USER_NAME="test" USER_ID="12345" USER_STATUS=" " USER_GENDER="F" /></root> 

@newXML = <root><row USER_KEY="1" USER_NAME="test" USER_ID="00000" USER_STATUS=" " USER_GENDER="F" /> 
</root>
```

I have like nearly 100 columns like that...I am not sure how to compare these tags and store them in my audit table with the filed name and previous value and changed value

In above values I have modified only USER_ID value. I am not sure how the string split function help me here. Please suggest....

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
DECLARE 
      @oldXML NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @newXML NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
      @oldXML = '<root><row USER_KEY="1" USER_NAME="test" USER_ID="12345" USER_STATUS=" " USER_GENDER="F" /></root>' 
    , @newXML = '<root><row USER_KEY="1" USER_NAME="test" USER_ID="00000" USER_STATUS=" " USER_GENDER="F" /></root>'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT id, t.rn, token = SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX('" ', t.name) - 1)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              name = 
                SUBSTRING(
                      t.string
                    , number + 2
                    , ABS(CHARINDEX('="', t.string, number + 1) - number - 1))
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
            , id
        FROM (
            SELECT id = 1, string = @newXML

            UNION ALL

            SELECT id = 2, @oldXML
        ) t
        CROSS JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values n
        WHERE [type] = 'p'
            AND number <= LEN(t.string) - 1
            AND SUBSTRING(t.string, number, 2) = '="'
    ) t
)
SELECT t2.token
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE id = 1
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE id = 2
) t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn AND t1.token != t2.token
WHERE t2.token IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This works great man thanks...One last request though.how can i find the field name too..in this case USER_ID